# Adding links in XML an reading it to dataset to populate grid view

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, hyperlink

I have a requirement of getting data from xml file and showing that data in a grid view in c# windows application.

I have done that successfully using dataset.ReadXml() method.

But what i originally want is that ,i need to have certain links in my XML file.Then i have to show that link in the grid view.

E.g here is my sample xml

```
<gallery heading="Photography">
  <piece>
    <heading>Piece 1</heading>
    <desc><![CDATA[<a href='http://www.yourUrlGoesHere.com' target='_blank'>text</a>]]></desc>
    <image>1.jpg</image>
  </piece>

  <piece>
    <heading>Piece 2</heading>
    <desc><![CDATA[<a href='http://www.yourUrlGoesHere.com' target='_blank'>text</a>]]></desc>
    <image>2.jpg</image>
  </piece>

</gallery>
```

When i read this xml into a dataset then dataset is coming as empty,i guess it is due to the a href thing.When i removed the href thing then data grid populated correctly.What is the problem here?

Can anyone help me to get over this.

Any help will be appreciated.Please help anyone.

Thanks

Comment: Instead of passing html link tags, just pass in the URL that you'd like to follow. Then add it to a DataGridViewLinkCell and handle the appropriate DataGridView click event to open the link when it's clicked.

Comment: But i m dynamically adding the dataset,so how can i add it to datagridviewlinkcell